# Snowflake CDC from S3 to Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have S3 bucket which is getting data from oracle to S3 everyday in the morning.
And with the use of Snowpipe, I am loading the data into Snowflake table named t1.
Now I am creating a new table t2 which will have cdc data from table t1.

I know that we can use task and stream to capture this. However streams will capture the event insert, update or delete on the record. But in our case we are appending the data in t1 and trying to get the update on id column to be loaded into t2.

For example on day 1, Table T1 will be loaded

```
Table t1
id      salary      load_date
--      ------      ----------
1       12000       12-03-2021
2       32000       12-03-2021
3       33000       12-03-2021
```

Table t2 will be directly loaded from t1

Table t2

```
id      salary      load_date
--      ------      ----------
1       12000       12-03-2021
2       32000       12-03-2021
3       33000       12-03-2021
```

Now on day 2 since we are appending the data into table t1 directly.
It looks like this

```
id      salary      load_date
--      ------      ----------
1       12000       12-03-2021
2       32000       12-03-2021
3       33000       12-03-2021
5       12500       13-03-2021
2       45000       13-03-2021
```

Now the table t2 should have updated value of id 2 and new value of id 5,
as below

```
id      salary      load_date
--      ------      ----------
1       12000       12-03-2021
2       45000       12-03-2021
3       33000       12-03-2021
5       12500       13-03-2021
```

I have a feeling stream wont help as there is no update in main table (t1),
So planning to use task with merge statement on table t2 from t1
something like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TASK EMPLOYEES_CDC
  WAREHOUSE = COMPUTE_WH
  SCHEDULE = 'USING CRON 0 9-17 * * SUN America/Los_Angeles'
AS
merge INTO t2 using (select * from t2 where load_date = current_date) t3 on t2.id = t3.id
      when matched then update t2.salary = t1.salary
      when not matched then insert (id,salary,load_date) values (t3.id,t3.salary,t3.load_date)
```

As merge looks a bit expensive.

Please suggest if this is an optimal way or there is a better way to do it.

Comment: How do you recognise deletes in T1? is there another column with the action type or something?

Comment: @SimonDarr There is no delete.. Just append table every day directly from S3 to t1. Delete update is not considered. and there is  no other column for action type

Comment: Since your source system never deletes data then your general append / merge process is fine I reckon.

Comment: @danD, i have a similiar requirement and i cannot use stream, can you help understand your query

Comment: @Asher which part of the solution u are getting confused into. What is the problem u are facing using stream

Comment: Similiar to you i have one table with the old data and then i have new data coming from S3 in the following avro structure .
{
  "after": {
    "COM_PCT": null,
    "DEPT_ID": 30,
    "EMAIL": "AKHOO",
    "EMPLOYEE_ID": 115,
    "FIRST_NAME": "ALEX",
    "LAST_NAME": "TIM",
    "HIRE": "1995-05-18 00:00:00",
    "MANAGER_ID": 114
  },
  "before": {},
  "current_ts": "2018-05-18 00:00:00:00",
  "op_ts": "2018-05-18 00:00:00:00",
  "op_type": "I",
  "pos": "00000000001123",
  "primary_keys": ["EMPLOYEE_ID"],
  "table": "HR.EMPLOYEE"
}

Comment: what I need is to get the latest Insert or Update transaction groupby the primary key and then merge to old data table using the primary key

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69717197/how-to-transform-incremental-update-data-into-structured-table-in-snowflake

Answer (score 0):

The solution you have described is the best way to address this.
A stream would definitely help, all you need to do is, change your merge statement to use the stream instead of table `t1`. Thus, your merge statement will only deal with delta.

Comment: I agree to use Stream, but only thing I wonder is since in table t1 it is always direct insert and no update.. then what will be the use of stream. is not it will be same as actual table. Like what difference will it make.

Comment: Stream will have new records inserted to t1 meaning delta, if you use t1 in merge you need to find out the latest record

Comment: Dan is using the load date to identify the latest records. Since the table will naturally be clustered by that column, it should be just as fast as using a stream I think?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you refer this [content](https://toppertips-bx67a.ondigitalocean.app/snowflake-stream-and-task-beginners-guide/) which could help you to identify how to apply stream.

You need to make sure that you create stream on external table and then consume it. Though stream on external table has some limitation but you check your use case too.